# Given $E[X] , \operatorname{Var}(X)$ and $Y\mid X \sim U(X,1)$, find $E[Y]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

> For $X, Y$ random variables, given $E[X] = \mu$ ; $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \sigma^2$; $Y\mid X \sim \text{Unif}(X,1)$: Find $E[Y]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$.

(1) To find E[Y], I used the law of conditional expectation:

From Y|X ~ U(X,1) --> E[Y|X] = X+1/2
Thus:
E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]] = E[X+1/2] = E[X/2] + E[1/2] = 0.5*(µ+1)

(2) To find Var(Y), I'm not sure how to evaluate the Var(Y|X) expression in:

Var(Y) = E[Var(Y|X)] + Var(E[Y|X])

I know that: Var(Y|X) = E[(Y - E[Y|X])² | X], but have no idea how to evaluate that.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What is variance of uniform distribution? You know the mean is (1+X)/2, now find the variance.

Comment: Oh! So, I can use Var(Y|X) = (1-X)²/12. This means Var(Y) = (1-X)²/12 + Var((X+1)/2) = σ² + µ² -2µ + 1.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law of total variance $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]]$$ can be evaluated just like you did for the law of total expectation, by first computing the inner conditional terms.

Clearly, you already know $$\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X] = \frac{X+1}{2}.$$  But you also know that for a uniform distribution on $[X,1]$, that $$\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X] = \frac{(1 - X)^2}{12}.$$  So now we have to compute $$\operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]] = \operatorname{Var}\left[\frac{X+1}{2}\right] = \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Var}[X+1] = \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Var}[X],$$ and $$\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{(1-X)^2}{12}\right] = \frac{1}{12}\operatorname{E}[(1-X)^2].$$  Here's a cute trick to calculate this expectation:  note
$$(1-X)^2 = (X-1)^2 = ((X-\mu)+(\mu-1))^2 = (X-\mu)^2 + 2(X-\mu)(\mu-1) + (\mu-1)^2$$ so that $$\operatorname{E}[(1-X)^2] = \operatorname{Var}[X] + 2(\mu-1)\operatorname{E}[X-\mu] + \operatorname{E}[(\mu-1)^2].$$  But $\operatorname{E}[X-\mu] = 0$ because $\mu = \operatorname{E}[X]$, and $(\mu-1)^2$ is constant, so we just have $$\operatorname{E}[(1-X)^2] = \operatorname{Var}[X] + (\mu-1)^2.$$

Comment: Cool! Just what I thought after @SubbornAtom's answer. Thanks heropup!

Comment: BTW, what about calculating Cov(X,Y)? I know that Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]. But, how do I calculate E[XY] ?

Comment: @David To use that formula to get $\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]$ you already have $\operatorname{E}[X]$ and $\operatorname{E}[Y]$ but you're missing $\operatorname{E}[XY]$.  But note you can also use total expectation for that:  $$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[XY \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}[X(X+1)/2] = \ldots.$$

Comment: As a matter of fact I was stuck on this too a while back. Just stumbled on it. Thanks for the pupper response :-)

Comment: @heropup Thanks. But, I'm afraid I'm a bit confused. 
(1) Why does E[XY] = E[E[XY | X]] ? Never seen the law of total expectations act on a product :-\
(2) Why does E[X*Y | X] = X*(X+1)/2 ?

Comment: @David Because the law of total expectation doesn't just apply to $Y$.  You can, for example, define some new random variable $W = XY$, and then $\operatorname{E}[W] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[W \mid X]]$ and since $Y \mid X$ is uniform on $[X,1]$, $W \mid X$ is just another random variable conditioned on $X$.  ($W \mid X$ happens to be uniform on $[X^2,X]$ but this fact is not needed to compute the expectation.)  And because the expectation is conditioned on $X$, $\operatorname{E}[XY \mid X] = X \operatorname{E}[Y \mid X] = X(X+1)/2$.